# Почему не получается поместить данные в название файла?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, есть класс из которого пытаюсь получить GPS данные в название файла с помощью метода toString. Вызываю его

```
DataGPS dataGPS = new DataGPS(locationManager);
```

но результат прежний название класса и хеш

В чём может быть причина ?

```
   public class DataGPS extends Activity {


private LocationManager locationManager;

 public DataGPS(LocationManager locationManager/*студия по чему то его не использует то есть делает прозрачным*/) {
    locationManager/*прозрачный*/ = this.locationManager;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(locationManager);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {// В onCreate ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМ TextView КОМПОНЕНТЫ  И ПОЛУЧАЕМ locationManager ЧЕРЕЗ КОТОРЫЙ И БУДЕМ РАБОТАТЬ
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

protected void onResume() {// В onResume ВЕШАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ НА ПРОВАЙДЕРА С ПОМОЩЬЮ МЕТОДА requestLocationUpdates
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*ТИП ПРОВАЙДЕРА*/,// НА ВХОД ЕМУ ПОДАЁМ
            1000 * 10/*МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ ВРЕМЯ ЗАПРОСА КООРДИНАТ*/, 10/*РАСТОЯНИЕ ОТОЙДЯ НА КОТОРОЕ ОБНОВЛЯЮТСЯ КООРДИНАТЫ*/, locationListener);
 }

@Override
protected void onPause() {//ОТКЛЮЧАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ МЕТОДА removeUpdates
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {//LocationListener СЛУШАТЕЛЬ РЕАЛИЗУЕТ ИНТЕРФЕЙС locationListener СО СЛЕДУЮЩИМИ МЕТОДАМИ

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//МЕТОД onLocationChanged НОВЫЕ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
        showLocation(location);                       //ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЗЫВАЕМ СВОЙ МЕТОД showLocation(location)КОТОРЫЙ НА ЭКРАНЕ ОТОБРОЗИТ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ОТКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ВКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ

    }


};

private void showLocation(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ЕГО МЕТОДОМ .getProvider()
    if (location == null)
        return;
   // location.getProvider();
    formatLocation(location);
}

private String formatLocation(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "lat = %1$.4f, lon = %2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `String.valueOf(Object obj)` имеет следующую реализацию:

```
public static String More ...valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Т.е. вызывается метод `toString()` переданного объекта. В вашем случае необходимо переопределить метод `DataGPS.toString()` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String provider);
    return (location == null) ? "null" : location.getLatitude() + "_" + location.getLongitude();
}
```

И еще, ваш конструктор класса `DataGPS` неправильный. Вы пытаетесь присвоить переданному в конструктор `LocationManager` внутренний `LocationManager`, что является бессмысленным. Перепишите конструктор так

```
public DataGPS(LocationManager locationManager) {
    this.locationManager = locationManager;
}
```

**UPD**: не сразу заметил что класс `DataGPS` наследуется от `Activity`, да еще и конструктор добавлен с параметром. Так делать нельзя, т.к. создание и запуск активити происходит не вами, а системой, соответственно и конструктор с параметром вызываться не будет. В данном случае необходимо производить инициализацию полей класса в методе `onCreate` и при формировании имени для фото просто использовать тот код, который я привел в методе `toString` в нужном месте. Либо использовать ваш метод `formatLocation(Location location)`

Comment: `@Override
public String toString() {
    Location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String provider);
    return (location == null) ? "null" : location.getLatitude() + "_" + location.getLongitude();
}`

Comment: Данный код к сожалению не работает подчёркивает красным  Location, provider, location. Честно сказать уже много вариантов перепробовал, но ничего не работает. Понять не могу вроде formatLocation(Location location) выдаёт строку почему в название её нет?

Comment: @VargSieg если у вас стоит ```targetSdk = 23```, то прежде чем получить координаты необходимо проверить и запросить соответствующее разрешение у пользователя и только потом запрашивать координаты. Поэтому студия и подчеркивает данный код как ошибочный. Метод ```foramatLocation``` у вас является приватным, внутри класса ```DataGPS``` кода по формированию названия я не вижу, соответственно как могут в названии файла оказаться координаты? Так же у вас есть метод ```showLocation``` который вызывает  ```foramatLocation```, но результат работы он никуда не сохраняет.

Comment: @VargSieg наверное вам стоит сначала разобраться в основах самого языка, а потом уже потихоньку переходить на ```Android```.

Comment: А разве этот код `return String.format(
                "lat = %1$.4f, lon = %2$.4f",
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());`не формирует название возвращая координаты в виде строки ?

Comment: @VargSieg возвращает, но вы же никуда его не сохраняете

Answer (score 1):

1. Экземпляр Activity нельзя создавать самостоятельно, и использовать конструкторы с параметрами. Так уж устроен андройд.
2. В название какого файла вы хотите поместить GPS, а главное зачем?

Comment: местоположение в котором было сделано фото обычно в EXIF раздел файла фотографии вставляют а не в название

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, все дело в реализации `toString` класса `LocationManager`. `toString` в нем судя по всему не переопределен и используется метод класса `Object`, который как раз имя класса и хэш возвращает.